# How to browse & display excel sheet in web browser using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, excel

i want to browse the excel input file & display it on web browser & it must be editable on web browser,
i am using C# asp.net for coding. Any help would be gr8. Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the options you have are HTML tables or  Google Spreadsheets / Microsoft Excel Online.

For more info:

http://www.labnol.org/software/embed-tables-spreadsheet-data-in-websites/7435/

Answer (score 0):

In the webform:

---

Code behind:

```
    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                Fileddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), Path.GetFileName(filePath)));
            }                              
        }
    }
    protected void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        string filePath = Fileddl.SelectedItem.Value;
        Myframe.Visible = true;
        Myframe.Attributes.Add("src", "https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://www.yoursite.com/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    }
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Fileddl.SelectedItem.Value;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=https://www.yoursite.com/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
    
    protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Fileddl.SelectedItem.Value;
        File.Delete(filePath);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include explanation as well not just code.